# Is there a way to create a type-guard for nested key access in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am reworking an implementation which was previously made using vanilla Javascript. I ran into an interesting situation which I do have a solution for, but for which I thought I had a superior solution which does not appear to work.

Basically, I have an object with two nested objects, their indexes typed as the string literals of their keys, where both objects have some of the other objects keys but not a total overlap. Then, I have a function that can receive either key, and a second key to access one of the values in that object. I created custom type-guards for the key, and created a second set of type-guards to confirm the second key passed was a key of one of the objects. Then, I created a function that takes both keys, and should return an object with correctly matched keys. However, typescript does not seem convinced within the function that I am using my validator function, that the key returned from my function is only one that can definitely access the key of the upper level object.

That a really unclear explanation, and I think some example code will make it better, so here it is:

```
const decoder = {
    foo: {
      foo: "bar",
      bar: "foo"
    },
    bar: {
      foo: "bar",
    },
  };

type FooKeys = keyof typeof decoder["foo"];

type BarKeys = keyof typeof decoder["bar"];

const isFooKey = (key: string): key is FooKeys => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(decoder["foo"], key);

const isBarKey = (key: string): key is BarKeys => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(decoder["bar"], key);

const isFoo = (key: string): key is "foo" => key === "foo";

const isBar = (key: string): key is "bar" => key === "bar";

const validator = (key: string, secondKey: string) => {
if (isFoo(key) && isFooKey(secondKey)) {
    return { key, secondKey }
}

if (isBar(key) && isBarKey(secondKey)) {
    return { key, secondKey }
}

return false;
}

// Here comes where the issue arises
const someFunc = (key: string, nestedKey: string) => {
const validated = validator(key, nestedKey);

if (validated) {
    return decoder[validated.key][validated.secondKey];
}

return null;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working in the way I would tihnk it should, is this a shortcoming of typescript or is it an issue with my reasoning or implementation? If someone has a better solution for my problem, I would love to hear it!

Comment: Please try to ensure that your example code is a [mcve]; if you drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) the only issues present should be the ones you're asking about.  Right now it looks like there are a bunch of typos, and I don't currently have the bandwidth to fix those to get to the point where I can begin to answer the question.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry about that, I typed this in a rush myself. All of the issues have been fixed, the only issue present is the one I was referring to.

Comment: I don't get it... isn't `validated.key` going to be either `"foo"` or `"bar"`, so `validated[validated.key]` is going to be either `validated.foo` or `validated.bar`, but `validated` isn't going to have a key named `foo` or `bar`, just `key` and `secondKey`?  What am I missing about this?  I strongly suggest you take some time and verify that you have a [mcve]; check that the code actually demonstrates the issue you are seeing.  Review the guidelines on [ask] to improve the chances of having a fruitful experience on Stack Overflow.  Good luck again!

Comment: Ah, I see where the confusion arose, I had used the wrong variable in the spot that was supposed to display my issue. I once again fixed that issue and verified the issue that I am pointing at is now displayed. If you want to focus on where my confusion lies, look at where the error is, and then look at the types returned by `validator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that `validated` is what I've been calling a [correlated record type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and TypeScript doesn't really have good support for those.  The issue is that the types of `decoder[validated.key]` and `validated.secondKey` are both union types; the former is of type `{ foo: string; bar: string; } | { foo: string; }` and the latter is of type `"foo" | "bar"`.  TypeScript's type system is pretty much unable to represent the fact that there is a *correlation* between those.

In general, if I have two values of union types where each union type has two members, like `declare const x: A | B; declare const y: C | D;`, the *pair* `[x, y]` will be of a type similar to `[A, C] | [A, D] | [B, C] | [B, D]`.  But you happen to know that, for example, if `x` is of type `A`, then `y` will be of type `C` and vice versa... because the type of `x` is correlated to the type of `y`. So `[A, D]` and `[B, C]` are impossible.   And therefore `[x, y]` should only be of `[A, C] | [B, D]`.  But the compiler is unable to infer this by itself, so it complains about these impossible situations.

In your case, the compiler is unable to verify that `decoder[validated.key][validated.secondKey]` is going to be a valid indexing operation.  It thinks that `decoder[validated.key]` might be `{ foo: string }` while `validated.secondKey` might be `"bar"`.  And so it complains.

---

There are a few things you can do to work around this.  One is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry.  This is the least type safe but it doesn't change your runtime code:

```
(decoder[validated.key] as { foo: string, bar: string })[validated.key]
```

You've basically claimed that `decoder[validated.key]` is the intersection of both its possible types, so that you can safely index its `"foo" | "bar"` property.

---

You could write redundant code to lead the compiler through both possibilities:

```
validated.key == "foo" ?
  decoder[validated.key][validated.secondKey] :
  decoder[validated.key][validated.secondKey]
```

Here it uses [control flow analysis](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to narrow `validated` to the two possibilities, after which `validated.key` and `validated.secondKey` are no longer union types.

---

Those are the two main ways to deal with correlated records in general.  For your code a third possibility suggests itself: since your `validator()` function actually goes through both possibilities separately, you can move the indexing into that function to take advantage of the control flow analysis:

```
const validatorAndDecoder = (key: string, secondKey: string) => {
  if (isFoo(key) && isFooKey(secondKey)) {
    return { key, secondKey, val: decoder[key][secondKey] }
  }
  if (isBar(key) && isBarKey(secondKey)) {
    return { key, secondKey, val: decoder[key][secondKey] }
  }
  return null;
}

const someFunc2 = (key: string, nestedKey: string) => {
  const validated = validatorAndDecoder(key, nestedKey);
  if (validated) {
    return validated.val
  }
  return null;
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgU1IgTjAvDA3gWAFAwwBmIIAXNvoYSeTAEQBGAhivQDRXUsoX230uAX04EYPCrjE1SfHh2GihAbnz4oATwAOCGADFSAaQQaIGGAGsTIIjE06b8JCFQBtfqXoBdVXnXbdACFWY1NzKw1HewRHRGQEFHd5HzU8UEhYAEsIAxBQ8wAKCIpoFEywAHMASgoImGz9IxMzdAA+GAB5RgArJCgAOi0UECgRgP6AC2YIDoB3MAAFYZ0UTX7gZgAbTYK4lwT3AS92SxMq33x06HqIYJR8zCKTEqgyyprTjRuYO9CW9q6vWAAyGIzGOkm0zmi2WCTWG22u2cbiYrG8Jwi51SVyyOVIhWKMFK5WqtRM3w8IHoGHadXQ9IYAguaXA12ydwJzyJrxJHzqDVRbBpnwwDMF9GZOJgADctpk4MxRmhHoTiZUThBnGA4KEXm9qsKpIRMrYCtlck8NFUYAAyG03XKhAqa9I6s7Wo3UFAIKAAVxQYGwnw1WrdXyEwlSxtN7NYlutdpuvxMztDoSqHq4hG9foDQYiIdd+QjYhLXBz-sDRC2mt8ZbwAHoGzAABIJXSgAC2CDMswm7bs-ZuEF9ulY2R7l1ZsAgIG7el9YGAnI0epJJzAPagCDDa-ehq4Utlm3lip35mPp6Vlo3W536eZUfqpsvCu3cEzfmkMCR8USr7POB+giLwYGmINaD3CoTgkbl9RgIQqlcAD32AkwvCfQgpRAcw9jcFCdzQjQUm-KULAvOU30Il1wDDXxqBgEBXHI8CIiiAJHBADDSyfE0fwIj8gyzGAKzzASiNFRlPBgAB+YTCDwg5xJA5DKMA-oaO1UJQLIeSnD-VSTyooCVPEzSw24wh62zH1KxgMBfW2OtsWnGU1KVABBbUABFkQSFcoMLWjdTg3kDzEPizTxEB41te1zSaDRUyLd1KG-UTAywYMiTTEwTmPChFMSFTzO0hDIwimNbjjTE4qTEIU1K1LPRs3NMuypqNHyrZCr84r0NcTrQJLKzy1svMHKc-B6ylWd50XYAACYAtC9V7LvXdVoNNo0qw1yBIoozFRAFAvLgXy-xvdboHvM56Offj3J3T8GIytyjtQ48KtauzJs2OsgA)

Comment: This helps a lot, your third solution was the one I already implemented, but you did help me understand what it is that the compiler is having a hard time with. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

you can do this istead:

```js
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] {
    return o[propertyName];
}

function validator(obj: typeof decoder, key: string, secondKey: string) {
    if (isFoo(key) && isFooKey(secondKey)) {
        const item = pluck(obj, key);
        const subItem = pluck(item, secondKey);
        return subItem;
    }

    if (isBar(key) && isBarKey(secondKey)) {
        const item = pluck(obj, key);
        const subItem = pluck(item, secondKey);
        return subItem;
    }

    return null;
}
```

#### Explanation

> #### Index types
>
> With index types, you can get the compiler to check code that uses dynamic property names.

see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) (`pluck`)